# run the annotate gem inside rubymine

Tags: rubygems, rubymine

New to rails - what am I missing? Working through Hartl's Rails Tutorial, have been able to find ways to run all the previous "bundle exec" commands from inside RubyMine. But now I've installed the annotate gem (Chapter 6); the tutorial's instructions are to run "bundle exec annotate". Is there an equivalent that can be run from inside Rails?

(I've discovered how to run RSpec, git push, etc., from inside Rubymine but I can't find how to do this one.)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try using [External Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) for this?

Answer (score 10):

(RubyMine 5.0)

1. Run > Edit Configurations...
2. "Add New Configuration" (Green '+' upper left) > "Gem Command"
3. Name = "Annotate Gem"
4. Configuration tab > Gem name = annotate, Executable name = annotate
5. Bundler tab > enable "Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec)"
6. OK button to save configuration
7. Toolbar > Configuration selector = "Annotate Gem", click the Run button
8. Output displayed in the Run panel

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem running it remote on a virtual ubuntu box, the path being sent
from windows was like this and it could not be found.

```
 \usr\local\bin\annotate
```

I just added the right path in Ruby arguments input:

```
 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /usr/local/bin/annotate
```

I just started with rubymine and i doubt this is the right method.